# I have difficulties with rename and delete functions in C

Tags: c, file, delete-file, file-rename

I recently started to make a program in **C** just for fun, a program that memorize "bank accounts" in a file.

So I made a "delete" function which can delete a certain "account" by its Id. Here is how it should work: I create a temporary function and there I put all the "accounts" but not the one with the requested Id. Then, I delete the original file, and then rename the temporary file with the name of the original one.

That is how it should work but guess what, it`s not. I mean the function is working all and well just that the rename and delete functions are not working, they are giving the "-1" message.

I searched and I have found many questions on this subject even here on Stack Overflow but I could not find the answer, that is why I'm doing it.

The program is in romanian, I translated only the "delete" function for you guys.
If you need the whole program also, just tell me.

```
void delete()
{
  FILE *f,*g;
  struct date s;
  int c=0;
  char id[5],pass[10];
  g=fopen("temp.txt","w");
  if((f=fopen("baza.txt","r+"))==NULL){     /* checking the existence of the file */
    printf("Error - File not found! \n");
    getch();
    return;
  }
  printf("\nEnter the desired Id whose account you want to delete: ");
  scanf("%s",id);
  while(fscanf(f,"%s%s%s%s%s",s.id,s.nume,s.prenume,s.suma,s.parola)!=EOF)
  {
    if(strcmp(s.id,id)==0)
    {
      do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        if(c==0)
        {
          printf("Introduce the password for the account with ID %s: ", s.id);
          scanf("%s",&pass);
        }
        else{

          if(c==1)
          {
            printf("Wrong password, try again: ");
          }

          if(c>1&&c<6)
          {
            printf("Wrong password %d times!, try again: ",c);
          }

          if(c==6)
          {
            printf("Wrong password %d times, the program will shutdown! \n",c);
            printf("Press any key to exit..\n");
            getch();
            exit(0);
          }
          scanf("%s",&pass);

        }
        c++;
      }while(strcmp(s.parola,pass)!=0);

    }
    if(strcmp(s.id,id)!=0)
    {
      fprintf(g,"%10s%20s%25s%15s\n",s.id,s.nume,s.prenume,s.suma);
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(g);

  }
  rename("temp.txt","baza.txt");
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Consider separation of concerns: Functions and structures to manage your accounts which do not interact with the user, and a userinterface which uses those.

Comment: You call rename() twice. - Also it is not necessary to remove() the original file first. rename() will happily replace it.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for your help but still not working...

Comment: @user3537727: Try *closing* the files before you delete/rename them (`fclose()`). As far as I know, you cannot delete or rename files which are in use.

Comment: @user3537727: Please do not significantly change your question without indication, especailly the code. Leave an obvious update-marker which clarifies what and that you changed something.

Comment: @MartinR but I have already closed both files before renaming or I`m such a noob and I didn`t but from what I know I closed them using fclose(f) and fclose(g) right before renaming.

Comment: Also, please remember that `scanf` can fail, always test to make sure it assigned all inputs.

Comment: @Deduplicator, sorry, I`m a noob I know, this is my first question, so I will not repeat it again..

Comment: You are right, I had overlooked that.

Comment: @Deduplicator there is no problem with the `scanf`, I`ve checked it

Comment: How did you check it? Tried to enter a name when a number was expected?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes I tried and it works. For Id howewer if I introduce a name or something it has to have max 5 characters otherwise it wont work but that`s normal having Id[5]

Answer (score 0):

try this so printf dont call again rename to try to call a file that does not exist.

```
   int returnvalue = rename("temp.txt","baza.txt");
      printf("%d",returnvalue);
      getch();
```

Comment: it didn`t work unfortunately :( I can`t figure out what`s the problem... but thank you for your help, it is a good thing what you say!

Comment: sorry that it didnt help, same problem??

Comment: You have nothing to be sorry about friend :) but still it doesn`t work. I thought it may be something about permissions but it`s not that, I`ve checked it. Also the file exists, so I don`t know what the problem may be...

Comment: put the fclose() out of the cycle while , you are trying to close the files multiple times, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried but no results.. However, I checked and at least I can say for sure that the delete thing works I mean, the accounts excepting the deleted one are copied in the temp.txt file but the problem is at renaming the `file`. I checked the `fclose` functions. Both `fclose(f)` and `fclose(g)` are returning `0` so the files are succesfully closed. I am administrator on my laptop so I have permission to read and write,so I don`t know what to say.

Comment: what is the return valor of rename()  ???  and  The new name must not be the name of an existing file or directory. its what I found so try  to rename bazar to another name then rename temp to bazar try it and tell me how it goes

Comment: I tried this but still it does not work, both `rename` are returning `-1`

Comment: are the documents in the same folder as the program? if they are then i dont know what else could it be

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem 2 min ago. My problem is solved when ı realised that ı was trying to delete the file after ı rename it. I think program do not change the name because that name is already taken. When ı first delete the old file and after that renam it, it worked.